# share a photo that save in internal storage

Tags: android, share

I want to write a program that share photos.
I want share them from internal storage and I have address of them .
they are store on phone but they are private 
what should I do?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void shareImage(String filepath, String appPackage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setPackage(appPackage);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filepath));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The appPackage for whatsapp for example is: "com.whatsapp"